# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 0 > 0

Tags: android, runtime-error, row, realm, indexoutofboundsexception

I try to read mydata with Realm in android calling two database like this

Fragment1.class

```
   public Model1 searchPerson1(int personId) {
    RealmResults<Model1> results1 = myRealm.where(Model1.class).equalTo("id", personId).findAll();

    myRealm.beginTransaction();
    myRealm.commitTransaction();

    return results1.get(0);
}
```

Fragment2.class

```
    public Model2 searchPerson2(int personId) {
    RealmResults<Model2> results2 = myRealm.where(Model2.class).equalTo("id", personId).findAll();

    myRealm.beginTransaction();
    myRealm.commitTransaction();

    return results2.get(0);
}
```

and it shows below error at RealmResults. I am using those two methods in different fragments. Please someone help me

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 0 > 0
```

Comment: In this line `rsChap.get(position).getId()`, check your `position` index. And this has nothing to do with `realm`.

Comment: I have written my code. please help me

Comment: This error is here because there is no object returned in RealmResult. so you have to check if the RealmResult.size() is greater then zero. then only do the .get(0). this will stop the crash. but you should check your logic that why there is no result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check count of objects in your query result before you try to get an object from position:

```
RealmResults<QuestionRealm> rsQues;
if(rsChap.size() > position && position >= 0){
    rsQues = myRealm.where(QuestionRealm.class)
                    .equalTo("chapter_id",rsChap.get(position)
                    .getId())
                    .findAll();
}
```

Comment: @ahmedsharief, error still happen because you try to take element at 0 position but `RealmResults` is empty. You need to check available count of items before request item from position (i.e. before your call get() method)

Comment: Your code is not working. Can you just update the code based on my code

Comment: @ahmedsharief, can you explain, how you try to use suggested code? Which error is happen?

Comment: I am saving my data in realm database and i am reading that data using card view. I mean when i click the card view the available textviews should be viewed in an activity

Comment: @ahmedsharief, _why your text view is not showing data?_ - it's another question. You need ask it separate with posting all required code.

Comment: I  just wanna know why this error is coming. It will resolve all the things